# Vertical spacing with formulas

Tags: line-spacing

I am having trouble with vertically centering all of my formulas between paragraphs and when using itemize. I am using LuaLatex and no usepackages for formula placement.

Code:

```
\begin{equation}
    \boxed{f_{ft,r2.5,prisme}=0.37f_{R3,prisme}}\label{eq:reststrekkfasthet.1}
\end{equation}

\begin{itemize}
    \item f\begin{footnotesize}{ft,r2.5,prisme}\end{footnotesize} = Reststrekkfastheten til fiberbetongen ved 2.5 mm rissutvidelse \cite{NB15}.
\end{itemize}

\begin{equation}
    \boxed{f_{ftm,r2.5,gulv}=0.75\cdot f_{ft,r2.5,prisme}}\label{eq:Mreststrekkfasthet.1}
\end{equation}

\begin{itemize}
    \item f\begin{footnotesize}ftm,r2.5,gulv\end{footnotesize} = Midlere reststrekkfasthet til fiberbetongen \cite{NB15}.
\end{itemize}
```

[image]

Any tips? I would really like to adjust all the formulas in one go, if that is possible.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Select code and click the button marked `{}`, then it will be shown properly.

Comment: Please make your code snippet compilable!

Comment: Why are you opening and closin `itemize`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One `itemize` environment, with several `\item` statements, should suffice. Also, don't leave blank lines (which create paragraph breaks) between the item's statement and the associated `equation` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[dutch]{babel} % ? Swedish? Norwegian?
\usepackage{amsmath,siunitx}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}

\item Some initial claim \dots
\begin{equation}\label{eq:reststrekkfasthet.1}
    \boxed{f_{\textrm{ft},\textrm{r2.5},\textrm{prisme}}
        =0.37f_{R3,\textrm{prisme}}}
\end{equation}

\item $f_{\textrm{ft},\textrm{r2.5},\textrm{prisme}}$\quad 
Reststrekkfastheten til fiberbetongen ved \SI{2.5}{\milli\meter} rissutvidelse \cite{NB15}.
\begin{equation}\label{eq:Mreststrekkfasthet.1}
    \boxed{f_{\textrm{ftm},\textrm{r2.5},\textrm{gulv}}
        =0.75 f_{\textrm{ft},\textrm{r2.5},\textrm{prisme}}}
\end{equation}

\item $f_{\textrm{ftm},\textrm{r2.5},\textrm{gulv}}$\quad 
Midlere reststrekkfasthet til fiberbetongen \cite{NB15}.

\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This was of great help, thank you!

I have another question if that's ok.

When i place formulas inside the itemization, they are centered differently from normal. Is there a way to get the same centering for formulas inside itemization mode?

Comment: @HaraldKyllingstad - There are probably many ways to achieve your objective. One particular way is as follows: (i) Load the `enumitem` package in the preamble, and (ii) replace `\begin{itemize}` with `\begin{itemize}[wide=0pt, leftmargin=*]`. This'll get you almost all the way to your objective. If equation centering has to be absolutely the same inside and outside of `itemize` environments, leave off the option `leftmargin=*`. However, this will also entail the text associated with an `\item` no longer having hanging indentation from the second row; this may, or may not, be acceptable to you.

Answer (score 4):

The vertical spacings before and after an `itemize` environment add  up to `\abovedisplayskip`. Just use a single `itemize` and no blank space between items and equations.

I took the opportunity to add some improvements to your code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[detect-all]{siunitx}
\newcommand{\wideboxed}[1]{\fboxsep=5pt\boxed{\;#1\;}}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}[before=\sffamily]
\item FR3G = Gjennomsnittskraften avleste ved \SI{2.5}{mm} rissutvidelse \cite{NB15} 
\begin{equation}
    \wideboxed{f_\text{ft,r2.5,prisme}=0.37f_\text{R3,prisme}}\label{eq:reststrekkfasthet.1}
\end{equation}

    \item f\textsubscript{\footnotesize ft,r2.5,prisme} = Reststrekkfastheten til fiberbetongen ved \SI{2.5}{mm} rissutvidelse \cite{NB15}.
\begin{equation}
    \wideboxed{f_\text{ftm,r2.5,gulv}=0.75 · f_\text{ft,r2.5,prisme}}\label{eq:Mreststrekkfasthet.1}
\end{equation}

    \item f\textsubscript{\footnotesize ftm,r2.5,gulv} = Midlere reststrekkfasthet til fiberbetongen \cite{NB15}.
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think that `f\begin{footnotesize}{ft,r2.5,prisme}\end{footnotesize}` produces a weird-looking result. Give `f\textsubscript{ft,r2.5,prisme}` a try?

Comment: @Mico: You're absolutely right. Of course I focused on the main point of the question. Maybe, since the O.P. seemed to want `footnotesize`,  something like  `f\textsubscript{\footnotesize ft,r2.5,prisme}`?

Comment: Both `\footnotesize` and `\scriptsize` should be OK.